# Spring security 401 when expecting 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http, spring-security

In my spring security setup using Java 21 & SB 3.2, I've configured spring security to permit all requests matching "/hello/**"

This works when i'm accessing an existing endpoint, but for endpoints where I expect a 404 (non-existing ones) I get a 401. When I change

`anyRequest().authenticated())`

Into:

`anyRequest().permitAll())`

I get the 404 I want, suggesting that the matching is not working, how do I circumvent this?

SecurityConfig:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

        var anonymousRequestMatcher = new OrRequestMatcher(
                requestMatcher("/hello/**"),
                requestMatcher("/anonymous/**")
        );

        return httpSecurity
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorization ->
                        authorization
                                .requestMatchers(anonymousRequestMatcher).permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .exceptionHandling(exceptionHandling ->
                        exceptionHandling
                                .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(UNAUTHORIZED))) // 401 for unauthenticated
                .build();

    }

    private AntPathRequestMatcher requestMatcher(String pattern) {
        return new AntPathRequestMatcher(pattern);
    }
}
```

Simple Controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController {

    @GetMapping
    public String hello(){
        return "hello world";
    }

}
```

With no authentication/authorization getting the default "/hello" path gives me a 200 with "hello world". However, "hello/123" results in a 401.

Comment: @Gilles this is a great link, I already had the Advice set to what is shown in the post. What was missing was : 

```spring.mvc.static-path-pattern: /static.```